# Why are my characters not available for the Witch Hunt DLC?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I have two characters that have finished the game, one of which I romanced with Morrigan during the game. That is the character I want to do the DLC with in case the story is different with a character that romanced with her, but he is greyed out (as is the other character I finished the original game with). I haven't done any of the other DLC with these characters.

Do I have to do other DLC with those characters before I can do Witch Hunt?

Why are these characters not usable with Witch Hunt?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the latest patch?  It appears from the Wiki that some issues with [loading the DLC](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Witch_Hunt#Patch) are fixed as of 1.1:

> Players who were getting 'Unable to Load Area' are now able to play
>   the DLC.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the ritual or not, its vital to the DLc that you did cause if you didn't your character is actually dead and the reason for Morigan to be on the run is so much less. Seeing as the ritual is the reason for her to be leaving.

If that isn't the case then it could be something alike not being high enough level I'm not certain, and the story changes if you've been in a romance with her.

Comment: Yes I completed the ritual. The character that romanced with her did the ritual himself, and the other I believe I sent Alistair to do the dirty work. I don't know if it is a level problem, as I said in the question, I haven't done the other DLC yet.